# How to create subdomain using BIND and domain name server

Tags: networking, server, dns

I want to understand the dns and configuration domain.
It is simple to configure using cpanel but I want to configure on server using BIND tool.
How to bind subdomain using name server like **test.domain.com**

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I bought a domain from a hosting firm.

```
ns1.xxxxx.com  
ns2.xxxxx.com
```

**Contents of File: /etc/named.conf**

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    allow-query     { any; };
    recursion no;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";


zone "ns1.xxxxx.com" {type master;file "/var/named/ns1.xxxxx.com.db";};
zone "ns2.xxxxx.com" {type master;file "/var/named/ns2.xxxxx.com.db";};
```

**Contents of File: /var/named/ns1.xxxxx.com.db**

```
$TTL 14400
ns1.xxxxx.com.      86400      IN      SOA      ns1.xxxxx.com.      info.xxxx.com.      (
                    2013071600 ;serial, todays date+todays
                    86400 ;refresh, seconds
                    7200 ;retry, seconds
                    3600000 ;expire, seconds
                    86400 ;minimum, seconds
      )
ns1.xxxxx.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.xxxxx.com.
ns1.xxxxx.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.xxxxx.com.
ns1.xxxxx.com. 14400 IN A ipaddress
test 14400 IN A ipaddress
```

**Contents of File: /var/named/ns2.xxxxx.com.db**

```
$TTL 14400
ns2.xxxxx.com.      86400      IN      SOA      ns1.xxxxx.com.      info.xxxx.com.      (
                    2013071600 ;serial, todays date+todays
                    86400 ;refresh, seconds
                    7200 ;retry, seconds
                    3600000 ;expire, seconds
                    86400 ;minimum, seconds
      )
ns2.xxxxx.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.xxxxx.com.
ns2.xxxxx.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.xxxxx.com.
ns2.xxxxx.com. 14400 IN A ipaddress
test 14400 IN A ipaddress
```